# DES ECB C# encryption/decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, des, ecb

I have a problem with decryption of data previously encrypted. I am using the sequential encrypt-decrypt-encrypt with three different keys to get triple des effect. The encryption function works correctly (returns 8-byte array), but the decryption function returns empty array.

```
    public static byte[] EncryptDES(byte[] clearData, byte[] key) 
    { 
        DES desEncrypt = new DESCryptoServiceProvider(); 
        desEncrypt.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; 
        desEncrypt.Key = key; 
        ICryptoTransform transForm = desEncrypt.CreateEncryptor(); 
        MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream(); 
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, transForm, CryptoStreamMode.Write); 
        cryptoStream.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length); 
        byte [] encryptedData = encryptedStream.ToArray(); 
        return encryptedData;
    }

    public static byte[] DecryptDES(byte[] clearData, byte[] key)
    {
        DES desDecrypt = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        desDecrypt.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        desDecrypt.Key = key;
        ICryptoTransform transForm = desDecrypt.CreateDecryptor();
        MemoryStream decryptedStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(decryptedStream, transForm, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
        byte[] encryptedData = decryptedStream.ToArray();
        return encryptedData;
    }

    public static byte[] Encrypt3DES(byte[] clearData, byte[] key0, byte[] key1, byte[] key2) 
    {
        byte[] encryptedData1 = new byte[clearData.Length];
        byte[] encryptedData2 = new byte[clearData.Length];
        byte[] encryptedData3 = new byte[clearData.Length];
        encryptedData1 = DESCrypto.EncryptDES(clearData    , key0);
        encryptedData2 = DESCrypto.DecryptDES(encryptedData1, key1);
        encryptedData3 = DESCrypto.EncryptDES(encryptedData2, key2);
        return encryptedData3;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably finalization (Flush final block or something like that) or padding related.

Comment: Thanks, the "(Flush final block" and padding set to none helped.

Comment: btw why are you doing something so weird in the first place? .net has built in 3DES support, and ECB is the wrong choice in most applications too.

Comment: Please post the "fixed" code as it is still wrong. You need to close the CryptoStream after use.

Comment: Setting padding to none will not work for you. It works ONLY when the length of the plaintext is a multiple of 8.

Answer (score 0):

[TripleDES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.aspx) already exist in the Framework but I guess you want to roll your own implementation for educational purposes.

You're making things more complicated than necessary. Since you are using streams why don't you chain them all instead:

```
public static byte[] TripleDESEncrypt(byte[] plainText, byte[] key1, byte[] key2, byte[] key3)
{
  var des = DES.Create();
  des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

  des.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
  des.Key = key3;
  var encryptor1 = des.CreateEncryptor();

  des.Key = key2;
  var decryptor = des.CreateDecryptor();

  des.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
  des.Key = key1;
  var encryptor2 = des.CreateEncryptor();

  byte[] result;
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (var cs1 = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor1, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    using (var cs2 = new CryptoStream(cs1, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    using (var cs3 = new CryptoStream(cs2, encryptor2, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
      cs3.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);

    result = ms.ToArray();
  }


  return result;
}
```

```
public static byte[] TripleDESDecrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key1, byte[] key2, byte[] key3)
{
  var des = DES.Create();
  des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

  des.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
  des.Key = key1;
  var decryptor1 = des.CreateDecryptor();

  des.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
  des.Key = key2;
  var encryptor = des.CreateEncryptor();

  des.Key = key3;
  var decryptor2 = des.CreateDecryptor();

  byte[] result;
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (var cs1 = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor1, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    using (var cs2 = new CryptoStream(cs1, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    using (var cs3 = new CryptoStream(cs2, decryptor2, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
      cs3.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);

    result = ms.ToArray();
  }


  return result;
}
```

Make note of the usage of `using` blocks and also how the padding is applied to the different streams.

The framework [TripleDES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.aspx) is about 2.5 times faster than the above code.

```
public static byte[] TripleDESEncryptFramework(byte[] plainText, byte[] key)
{
  var tdes = TripleDES.Create();
  tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
  tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
  tdes.Key = key;

  var encryptor = tdes.CreateEncryptor();

  byte[] result;
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
      cs.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);

    result = ms.ToArray();
  }

  return result;
}
```

If you want to compare the results of the two different encryption methods then you need to remember that the 24-bit key for [TripleDES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.aspx) is actually the 3 keys put in one array:

```
[  key1  ][  key2  ][  key3  ]
==============================
[            key             ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock(). Its code works great:

```
   //ENCRYPT
   public static byte[] EncryptDES(byte[] clearData, byte[] key) 
   { 
       DES desEncrypt = new DESCryptoServiceProvider(); 
       desEncrypt.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; 
       desEncrypt.Key = key; 
       ICryptoTransform transForm = desEncrypt.CreateEncryptor(); 
       MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream(); 
       CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, transForm, CryptoStreamMode.Write); 
       cryptoStream.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
       cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
       return encryptedStream.ToArray();
   }

   //DECRYPT
   public static byte[] DecryptDES(byte[] clearData, byte[] key)
   {
       DES desDecrypt = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
       desDecrypt.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
       desDecrypt.Key = key;
       ICryptoTransform transForm = desDecrypt.CreateDecryptor();
       MemoryStream decryptedStream = new MemoryStream();
       CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(decryptedStream, transForm, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
       cryptoStream.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
       cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
       return decryptedStream.ToArray();
   }
```